# How to apply gradient color at the end of the content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to replicate the below-added image UI(taken from the [udemy.com](https://udemy.com) course description section). I was looking for a way to create a similar gradient UI on only some parts of the content as shown in the below image.

[image]

Here is the sample code sandbox where I have been experimenting https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-einstein-doeql?file=/src/Demo.js. I am trying to apply this exact ui to a `material-ui` card content. Here is my `Demo.js` where I have the card content defined

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345
  }
});

export default function ImgMediaCard() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardMedia
        component="img"
        alt="Contemplative Reptile"
        image="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503803548695-c2a7b4a5b875?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"
        title="Contemplative Reptile"
      />
      <CardContent>
        <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
          Lizard
        </Typography>
        <Typography
          className="content"
          variant="body2"
          color="textSecondary"
          component="p"
        >
          Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
          species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica Lizards are a
          widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000 species,
          ranging across all continents except Antarctica Lizards are a
          widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000 species,
          ranging across all continents except Antarctica Lizards are a
          widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000 species,
          ranging across all continents except Antarctica Lizards are a
          widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000 species,
          ranging across all continents except Antarctica Lizards are a
          widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000 species,
          ranging across all continents except Antarctica Lizards are
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <div className="button">
        <Button size="small">Read more</Button>
      </div>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

and my `styles.css`

```
.content {
  max-height: 100px;
}

.content:hover {
  max-height: none;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 5px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you can use linear gradient in css on lower div with class button to achieve the hiding effect.

Comment: Hell yeah! It did. Thanks a lot @kmoser

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question. If I do to the sample code sandbox, it actually expands on hover. Maybe you found the answer?